How to use Transfinite option in Gmsh to mesh an stl file
I'm working on the creation of a structured mesh for the FEM analysis of the ascending aorta. I start from an STL file and I apply algorithm 8, recombination with Blossom and then the algorithm 11 for the quasi-structured mesh. I have defined also some guiding splines on the surface of the artery and applied the tranfinite option. The result is not bad but it seems that the transfinite splines only "guide" meshing, although actually gmsh doesn't create nodes on the lines that I have defined, so it seems like it's not a proper  tranfinite. Is it due to the fact that I haven't created from zero my geometry with the CAD but I'm working on a geometry that derives from an stl file?
